# sorting an array of struct within array of struct c

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of structures by each member of the structure; ie, I want
to print 1 list sorted by each member of the structure.  When the members of the
structure are integers, no problem.  But one of the members is another array of structures,
and I also want to sort the whole mess by each  member of that structure.  Here is the code:

```
 #define PROPHET_COUNT 9000
 #define MAX_FAITH_COUNT 600

typedef struct s_ProphetStat {  
    int     precursorScore;
    int     cassandraScore;
    int     prophetId;} prophetStat;

typedef struct s_FaithStat{
    int     precursorScore;
    int     cassandraScore;
    int     faithId;
    prophetStat ProphetStat[PROPHET_COUNT];  } faithStat; 

void fauxScoringFunction(faithStat *FaithStat)
{
    for (int faithIndex = 0; faithIndex < MAX_FAITH_COUNT; ++faithIndex){
        for (int prophetIndex = 0; prophetIndex < PROPHET_COUNT; ++prophetIndex){
            int randomNumber = rand();
            FaithStat[faithIndex].ProphetStat[prophetIndex].precursorScore +=   randomNumber;
            FaithStat[faithIndex].ProphetStat[prophetIndex].cassandraScore +=   randomNumber;
            FaithStat[faithIndex].precursorScore += randomNumber;
            FaithStat[faithIndex].cassandraScore += randomNumber; }}
}

typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);`enter code here`

   int compareFaithPrecursorScores(faithStat *faithA, faithStat *faithB){
 if (faithA->precursorScore > faithB->precursorScore) return 1; if (faithA->precursorScore < faithB->precursorScore) return -1; return 0; }
    int compareFaithCassandraScores(faithStat *faithA, faithStat *faithB) {
  if (faithA->cassandraScore > faithB->cassandraScore) return 1; if (faithA->cassandraScore < faithB->cassandraScore) return -1; return 0; }
    int cannotFigureOut(...) { return 0; }

void fakemain(void)
{
    faithStat   *FaithStat =  (faithStat *)   calloc(MAX_FAITH_COUNT,   sizeof(faithStat) );
    fauxScoringFunction(FaithStat);
    // sort by cumulative precursorScore for each faith 
    qsort(FaithStat, MAX_FAITH_COUNT, sizeof(faithStat *), (compfn) compareFaithPrecursorScores);
    // print results();
    // sort by cumulative precursorScore for each faith
    qsort(FaithStat, MAX_FAITH_COUNT, sizeof(faithStat *), (compfn) compareFaithCassandraScores);
    // print results()
    // sort by prophet precursor score
    qsort(FaithStat, MAX_FAITH_COUNT * PROPHET_COUNT, sizeof(faithStat *), (compfn) cannotFigureOut);
}
```

It is the "cannotFigureOut()" compare function that I am trying to write.  (I am compiling C code using VS2010 C++ (not my decision), thus the nasty calloc cast.  All other ugliness is mine.)

Edits:  in trying to simplify, botched the compare functions. Fixed that.  Also,
Edit:  I omitted an important piece of information:  the set of Prophets is the same for each faith.  So what I want to do is sort by
the *cumulative* precursor scores (and then, separately, by the cumulative cassandra score) of each prophet.  That is:   Prophet[0] cumulativeScore = (Faith[0].Prophet[0].precursorScore + 
(Faith[1].Prophet[0].precursorScore ...  Faith[ MAX_FAITH_COUNT - 1].Prophet[0].precursorScore);

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you want to be able to sort on e.g. `faithStat.prohetStat[0].precursorScore`, and on `faithStat.prohetStat[0].cassandraScore`, and on `faithStat.prohetStat[1].precursorScore`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, the latter: each faith gives different scores to each of the prophets, but they all share the same list of prophets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `return (a,b);` just returns `b`; in both your `compareFaithPrecursorScores` and `compareFaithCassandraScores` you probably want to replace `,` with `-`. Now, you only have *faiths* allocated in your main, so in the last one you should sort the same `FaithStat` of that same length as before: `MAX_FAITH_COUNT`, not `MAX_FAITH_COUNT * PROPHET_COUNT`.

Now in your `cannotFigureOut`, you just compare two faithStats, as before, so the signature is still the same:

```
int cannotFigureOut(faithStat *faithA, faithStat *faithB){
 .... }
```

(edit:) ok, so (after your clarifications) that's not called *cumulative* at all, that's misleading. You meant *total* score. What your last addition seems to say is that you want to sort *another array* altogether, this time of 9000 prophets (and not of 600 faiths). Each prophet's score will be the sum of his scores across all faiths; just make a function to fill the prophets array up after it's created, then sort as usual.

You may use the same `prophetStat` structure to hold the total scores this time, and not the per-faith values, so that the signature will be

```
int cannotFigureOut(prophetStat *prophetA, prophetStat *prophetB){
 .... }
```